# How can I call a function of all variadically inherited classes?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, multiple-inheritance, variadic-functions, fold

I'd be grateful to any template gurus out there for some help on this one. I'm using CRTP for a mixin class and would like to be able to pass arguments to a function of the derived class and have it call the inherited functions of all mixins and forward the appropriate number of arguments. E.g.:

```cpp
template<Host> struct Mixin1 { void Initialize(int, double); };
template<Host> struct Mixin2 { void Initialize(); };
template<Host> struct Mixin3 { void Initialize(double); };

template <template<class> class... Components>
struct Entity : public Components<Entity<Components...>>...
{
    template<template<class> class ...Types, template<template<typename>typename...> class T, class... Args>
    void Initialize(const T<Types...>&, Args&&... args) {
      (Types<Entity<Types>>::Initialize(forward<Types>(args)),...);
    }
}
```

And use like:

```cpp
entity.Initialize(42,42.0,42.0);
```

Is it possible to pass the appropriate number of arguments to each? The code above of course doesn't work but my idea was to try the method of instantiating an empty template with the types of each of the arguments (i.e. `Variad<int, double> v1; Variad<> v2; Variad<double> v3;`) and pass a variad containing all those into the function along with the arguments but I can't seem to figure out how to split the arguments correctly.

Comment: Just to be sure... given `Entity<Mixin1, Mixin2, Mixin3> entity;`, from the call `entity.Initialize(1, 2.0, 3.0);` do you want are called `Initialize(1, 2.0)` from `Mixin1`, `Initialize()` from `Mixin2` and `Initialize(3.0)` from `Mixin3`?

Comment: It should be possible to come up with some messy TMP solution to this, but it would break as soon as someone made one of the mixin class's `Initialize` methods overloaded or a template. Instead, you should have `Entity::Initialize` take a list of *tuples* of arguments, forwarding arguments from each tuple to the corresponding mixin's `Initialize` method.

Comment: Yes @max66 that's the intended behavior.

Comment: @Brian a messy TMP solution is actually alright by me, it's safe to assume the function will bever be templated or overloaded. The main need is to use the function with perfect forwarding and no copying. If I'm not mistaken using tuples will require copying at least once no?

Comment: BTW, I think that TMP solution would create the tuple anyway (and with tuple, you might have `tuple<T&, U&&>` to avoid extra copy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass the appropriate number of arguments to each?

Not in a simple way, as far I can understand.

Surely it's possible, counting argument of every method and using recursion (also recursive variadic lambdas) and SFINAE.

I've developed the following example just because I love template metaprogramming; but I'm the first to say that it's a delirious nightmare.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename R, typename T, typename ... As>
constexpr std::size_t numArgs (R(T::*)(As...))
 { return sizeof...(As); }

template <typename>
struct Mixin1
 {
   void Initialize (int i, double d)
    { std::cout << "I1: " << i << ", " << d << std::endl; }
 };

template <typename>
struct Mixin2
 {
   void Initialize ()
    { std::cout << "I2:" << std::endl; }
 };

template <typename>
struct Mixin3
 {
   void Initialize (double d)
    { std::cout << "I3: " << d << std::endl; }
 };

template <template <typename> class ... Cs>
struct Entity : public Cs<Entity<Cs...>>...
 {
   template <std::size_t Pos, typename ... Ts,
             typename F, std::size_t I0, std::size_t ... Is,
             typename ... As>
   std::enable_if_t<(Pos == I0)>
      Ih2 (F const & f, std::index_sequence<I0, Is...> const &,
           As && ... as)
    { 
      f(); // exec an Initialize();

      Ih1<Ts...>(std::index_sequence<Is...>{}, std::forward<As>(as)...);
    }

   template <std::size_t Pos, typename ... Ts,
             typename F, std::size_t I0, std::size_t ... Is,
             typename A0, typename ... As>
   std::enable_if_t<(Pos < I0)>
      Ih2 (F const & f, std::index_sequence<I0, Is...> const & is,
           A0 && a0, As && ... as)
    { Ih2<Pos+1u, Ts...>
       ([&a0, &f](auto && ... as2) { f(std::forward<A0>(a0),
                                     std::forward<decltype(as2)>(as2)...); },
        is, std::forward<As>(as)...); }

   template <int = 0>
   void Ih1 (std::index_sequence<> const &)
    { }

   template <typename T0, typename ... Ts,
             std::size_t ... Is, typename ... As>
   void Ih1 (std::index_sequence<Is...> const & is, As && ... as)
    { Ih2<0u, Ts...>
       ([this](auto && ... as2)
           { T0::Initialize(std::forward<decltype(as2)>(as2)...); },
        is, std::forward<As>(as)...); }

   template <typename ... As>
   void Initialize (As && ... args)
    { Ih1<Cs<Entity<Cs...>>...>
       (std::index_sequence<numArgs(&Cs<Entity<Cs...>>::Initialize)...>{},
        std::forward<As>(args)...); }
 };

int main ()
 {
   Entity<Mixin1, Mixin2, Mixin3> entity;

   entity.Initialize(1, 2.0, 3.0);
 }
```

As said in a comment, this solution doesn't works in case of overloading, or template, for `Initialize()` in the single `Components`.

Comment: Hot diggity he done it! I almost wonder if there might be a slightly cleaner way to do it with fold expressions? I'll keep playing with it to see if I can't find a way. Thanks! Luckily this is just a personal project so no one will have to see it

Comment: Btw, it's missing a && after auto in the IH1 lambda

Comment: @GarinStrader - "it's missing a && after auto in the IH1 lambda" - D'oh! You're right; corrected; thanks. And neither g++ nor clang++ signaled this.

Comment: Just curious (so I don't spend to much time spinning my wheels), it seems like it's not possible to make this work for constructors?

Comment: Actually, turns out I don't need it to, but I'm still curious if it's possible. Pretty sure it's not, there isn't really a way to call each constructor in the initializer list using this structure

Comment: @GarinStrader - constructors? well... maybe with delegating constructors... Not easy (well... more complicated) but I suppose it's possible.

Comment: Might you have any inkling as to why this won't compile with ICC? My (modified) code compiled fine with MSVC but not ICC so I double checked with your code and it doesn't like ` { T0::Initialize(std::forward<decltype(as2)>(as2)...); },` and says both too many and too few arguments in function call. I haven't seen anyone with issues with variadic lambdas in ICC like this